# Conditional replace of strings in a row

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to replace a word in a string (paragraph) conditionally like  this example:

```
text = "here is a semi colon and a semi as an example and here again a semi colon"
```

I wanna replace "semi" by ":"
and
"semi colon" by ";"

But when i do:

```
re.sub(r'semi', r":", text)
```

I get:

```
text = "here is a : colon and a : as an example and here again a : colon"
```

So I don't want to change it if "semi colon" is in the text.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Replace `semi colon` by `;` first.

Comment: Looking for a more generic solution as sometimes I only need to change "semi" without never changing "semi colon" situations.

Comment: OK, then you should probably use a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a *negative lookahead* ("semi" *not* followed by "colon"):

```
re.sub(r'semi(?!\s*colon)', r":", text)
#'here is a semi colon and a : as an example and here again a semi colon'
```

Comment: thnx - @DYZ this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture both of your desired outputs, however maybe you want to replace them one by one:

```
(semi colon)|(semi(?!:(\scolon)))
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/77hPRi/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

Comment: You cannot use this regex for substitution, only for matching.